# Can I remove the "Log Out" item from the Apple menu?

Tags: user-account

Is it possible to remove "Log Out" from the Apple Menu? I know there used to be a tool that let you customize the Apple Menu (can't remember the name) but I doubt it's still working on Lion.

Preferably I'd like a Terminal command or something.

Comment: Is there a reason you're asking?

Comment: I wish I could move or copy the  "Log Out" item from the Apple Menu to the quick user switch menu at the right side of the menu bar. It seems a much more appropriate place for it.

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328980/log-out-from-user-switching-menu

Answer (score 4):

I've been looking at removing the Sleep and Shut Down options from the Apple Menu on our lab Macs. My focus was OS X 10.7.3.

I found that just removing the objects, as Daniel Lawson has suggested, also caused the Apple menu to crash when I clicked it.

After closer examination, I noticed that there were references to the Shut Down and Sleep objects elsewhere in the objects.xib file. After I removed both the objects and the references, the Apple menu behaved as expected, and did not show the Shut Down and Sleep options.

Here are my changes to the 10.7.3 objects.xib file:

File:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj/StandardMenus.nib/objects.xib
```

Changes:

```
# diff objects.xib ../StandardMenus.nib.ORIG/objects.xib 
185a186,189
>         <object class="IBCarbonMenuItem" id="236">
>           <string name="title">Sleep</string>
>           <ostype name="command">slep</ostype>
>         </object>
196a201,212
>         <object class="IBCarbonMenuItem" id="238">
>           <string name="title">Shut Down…</string>
>           <boolean name="dynamic">TRUE</boolean>
>           <boolean name="notPreviousAlternate">TRUE</boolean>
>           <ostype name="command">rsdn</ostype>
>         </object>
>         <object class="IBCarbonMenuItem" id="285">
>           <string name="title">Shut Down</string>
>           <boolean name="dynamic">TRUE</boolean>
>           <int name="keyEquivalentModifier">1572864</int>
>           <ostype name="command">shut</ostype>
>         </object>
242a259
>     <reference idRef="236"/>
358a376
>     <reference idRef="285"/>
401a420
>     <reference idRef="238"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

This appears to work, but make a good backup before proceeding; you're messing with system files!

Using [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/), open the file 
`/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj/StandardMenus.nib/objects.xib`

You'll need to use an account with administrate privileges, and you'll be prompted for your password. Find the lines that read

```
<object class="IBCarbonMenuItem" id="286">
  <string name="title">Log Out %@</string>
  <string name="keyEquivalent">Q</string>
  <boolean name="dynamic">TRUE</boolean>
  <int name="keyEquivalentModifier">1703936</int>
  <ostype name="command">rlgo</ostype>
</object>
```

and delete them. Save the file. Reboot.
Goodbye logout command.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this website](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050422121335362), the apple menu entries are kept here:

*/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj/StandardMenus.nib*

Otherwise you could try [this app](http://unsanity.com/haxies/fruitmenu) which apparently does the same thing but with a GUI

Comment: As of 1/15/2012, FruitMenu (along with all other Unsanity apps) does not work with Lion.