# Avoid inadvertent "Shut Down" of Mac

Tags: macos, shutdown

For a Mac mini or such acting as a server in a server room or [colo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colocation_centre), accidentally choosing the `Apple > Shut Down…` menu item is a major problem. Without physical access, you cannot start the Mac up again.

> Is there a way to **make it more difficult to inadvertently shut down** a Mac?

One workaround is to set `System Preferences > Energy Saver > Schedule (button) > Start up or wake (checkbox)` to boot the computer, say 2:00 AM if you often do admin work at midnight. But I'm looking ways to avoid the shut down problem in the first place.

Comment: don't you get a 1 minute count down ? where you can stop it

Comment: @Buscar웃 Yes, there's a countdown. But (1) that means the shutdown will occur if I look away, and (2) the default keystroke on the countdown dialog is the affirmative button, to immediately shutdown. Both of those behaviors are bad for a server. So, again, my question is about ways to avoid the problem in the first place (on server computers).

Answer (score 2):

You could remove `Shut Down…` from the menu entirely. [This Ask Different question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22535/can-i-remove-the-log-out-item-from-the-apple-menu) looks like it has instructions on how to do that. Good luck!