# Log out from user switching menu

Tags: macos, fast-user-switching

Can I move or copy the "Log Out" item from the Apple Menu to the fast user switching menu at the right side of the menu bar? It seems a much more appropriate place for it.

I'm running El Captain 10.11.6 (15G21013).

Comment: Related to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22535/can-i-remove-the-log-out-item-from-the-apple-menu